# Why I get "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame called `df`, with column `A`.
I do the following code:

```
df['A'][df['A'] < 4] = np.NaN
```

I get the following message :

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
df['A'][df['A'] < 4] = np.NaN
bla.py:763: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

The code works, `df` is changed after executing this line, so In practice it does not trying to change a copy of `df` but the original `df`

Why do I get this warning ?

P.S : I looked at similar questions on stack overflow but could't find an answer

Comment: Use `.loc` to assign value `df.loc[df['A'] < 4, 'A'] = np.nan`

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: @ResidentSleeper maybe the `.loc` will remove the warning, but still it doesn't explain why i'm getting a warning in the first place.

Comment: @OopsUser pretty good explanation in the answer linked by Anshul.